# How private is visual studio code on ubuntu?

Tags: privacy, visual-studio-code

I can install visual studio code on ubuntu bionic beaver. When I go to the software manager I find it in the list of applications but I do read that:

*"This application has no limitations and has access to all personal files and systems sources".*

Personal files? When I go to microsoft's privacy statement it all sounds pretty innocuous, telemetry and advertisements, nothing like that is mentioned but they are not saying exactly what they are accessing on my pc either. So how serious is this? Can they read my diary? Do they read my diary? I like Atom but it doesn't debug node.js as easily. Hence the question.

Thank you and greetings,
Karin Meersman

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're concerned about VS, have you tried Eclipse as a Development Environment?

Comment: Thank you very much, I found eclipse in the ubuntu software manager. Unfortunately I find the exact same statement about access to personal files. I just don't know what to think about it.

Comment: This seems to be a note particular to Snaps, which are in general supposed to be "sandboxed" in a separate environment. I wouldn't think too much of it to be honest. But if you're still concerned, you can always download Eclipse directly from their website. It doesn't even need to be installed, just unpack it and run it from anywhere. Just need to have a working Java environment for it.

Comment: I'm a javascript girl, have never worked with java. I'm doing courses on linux now and I'm learning a lot but still feel most comfortable working with js.I suspect you are right which means I could use Visual Studio Code, I hear people rave about it. I sent Canonical Ltd, the company behind the snap packages a mail. Let's see how and if they respond. Will let you know!

Comment: I'm not a guru here but AFAIU any binary in repository that wasn't build by compiling the source code has this message because it's, well, binary - you can't really say what it does exactly under the hood. This is the case with almost every single application on Windows operating system and the Windows itself, therefore, they don't post such warnings there. On Linux it's the other way around - source code is open by default and the inner workings of most applications can be freely audited so it makes sense to only display privacy warnings where it's not possible. Risk is usually negligible.

Comment: Thanks for providing this context. It puts things in perspective.I checked Atom, my favorite editor and again found the exact same phrase. So, it's too late anyway. Canonical invited me for a webinar but did not replay to my mail. I still think it's  a problem, on the one hand I am flooded with 'information', I mean, do you read all that text before you click 'agree'?, On the other it's either too vague or too extreme to be relied on. Luckily I am way too suspicious to put anything truly embarassing on my pc. I am at peace with it.